# How can I initialize CloudantToolkit and create local datastore?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, cloudant

MFP Foudantion provides CloudantToolkit SDK. The manual tells us how to create local datastore([Creating databases](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/cloud/data/t_data_sdk_db.html?locale=en)).But it uses IMFData SDK.

I think Cloudant toolkit doesn't depend on IMFData SDK.

```
//Get reference to data manager
IMFDataManager *manager = [IMFDataManager sharedInstance];
NSString *name = @"automobiledb";
NSError *error = nil;

//Create local store
CDTStore *store = [manager localStore:name error:&error];
```

Comment: Are you attempting to use Cloudant toolkit only or are you looking for more information on how to obtain and use IMFData SDK? We have a sample which shows the integration here:

https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/data/cloudant-nosql-db-api/

Here is the iOS specific tutorial as well:
https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/data/cloudant-nosql-db-api/ios-cloudant-nosql-db-api/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.  CloudantToolkit does not depend on IMFData.  IMFData depends on CloudantToolkit.

You can create a local store with CloudantToolkit.  CloudantToolkit does not have an initialization call.  Here is sample code to create a local store with just CloudantToolkit.

```
//Use CDTDatastoreManager to create CDTDatastore
CDTDatastoreManager *datastoreManager = existingDatastoreManager;
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *name = @"automobiledb";
CDTDatastore *cdtdatastore = [datastoreManager datastoreNamed:name error:&error];
if(error){
    NSLog(@"Could not create cdtdatastore: %@", error);
}

//Create local store
CDTStore *store = [CDTStore localStoreWithDatastore:cdtdatastore];
```

You will need to create a CDTDatastoreManager as shown in the documentation for CDTDatastore.  See https://github.com/cloudant/CDTDatastore

Comment: Thanks, Keven.It helps a lot.